# Is it possible to say 'double deck', if we speak about a shelf in a train?

Tags: vocabulary

Could you tell me , is it possible to say 'double deck', if we speak about a shelf in a train? Does this variant exist?

Comment: Have you looked up what the definition of "deck" is?

Comment: yep.  There are different meanings . Double- decker bus, double- deck on board ship, circle; layer, long fishing line having individual hooks attached by smaller lines at intervals; tier; floor. So i thought , if there is a double deck like the 2nd floor , maybe there is a double deck like the place in the train.

Answer (score 1):

"Double deck" almost always refers to two levels of floors (e.g. double decked ships, buses and even trains). I have never heard of two levels of shelving referred to as double decked, you would say "there are two shelves to put your stuff on". You might see the variant "rows of shelves".